# Using Jquery, toggle a replaceWith command to switch between an input

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a problem I cannot seem to solve.

I have a php and sql function that creates and populates a select drop-down. I need to be able to toggle this with a simple text input. I can use replaceWith() to get from the select drop-down to the text input but I cannot work out how to switch back to the original select drop-down.

```
 $('.plus').click(function() {
                            var id = $(this).closest('li').find('select').attr('id');
                            $(this).closest('li').find('select').replaceWith('<input class="new_input" type="text" id="' + id + '" />');                                     

                              });
```

So when .plus is clicked I need it to toggle between the select and input items. I am creating the new input in jquery as I need to dynamically assign the input's id. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't remove the SELECT, just hide & disable it, and remove the ID attibute. When you need to switch back to a SELECT, hide & disable the input, remove the ID attribute and restore it to the SELECT, which you then show and enable.

Comment: I'm being dim, could you possibly supply and example?